Числа заполнения в Python
Собственно, речь идет о модели, являющейся основой для вывода известных квантовых статистик БЭ и ФД:
Есть K+1 ячейка, в которых располагаются N частиц, ячейки пронумерованы, k=0, 1, 2, ..., К. В k-той ячейке могут "сидеть" $n_k$ частиц так, что $n_0 +n_1 + ... +n_k + ... + n_K = N$. $n_k$ называются числами заполнения. Надо выбрать наборы всех возможных чисел заполнения, то есть, все возможные строки $n_0, n_1, ..., n_k, ..., n_K$ при фиксированных К и N. Интересует не "теория", алгоритм и т.п., а конкретное воплощение в библиотеках "Питона" для анализа данных, таких как, например, Pandas, NumPy,SciPy и т.п.

Приведите пример конкретных данных. Хотя бы небольшой. Такие вопросы требуют наличия примеров. Описания формулами недостаточно.

То есть, вам нужно разложить N в сумму из K+1 слагаемых всеми возможными способами. Число способов Cnk(n + k, k) - число комбинаций размера k из набора размера n+k. Стандартных функций для генерации разложений не припомню - это ответ на ваш вопрос. Написать рекурсивный генератор несложно.

Stanislav Volodarskiy, да, совершенно верно, ровно K+1 слагаемых, которые могут быть нулевыми "(пустые ячейки). Кажется, это называется integer compositions по-английски
